# Spark sql query execution fails with org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am executing a simple create table query in spark sql using spark-submit(cluster mode). Receiving **org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException**. I could get few details on this issue over internet, one of the suggestion was to add the config **spark.sql.parquet.writeLegacyFormat=true**. The issue still persist after addding this setting.

Below is the query:

```
spark.sql("""
CREATE TABLE TestTable
 STORED AS PARQUET 
    AS 
SELECT Col1, 
       Col2, 
       Col3 
FROM Stable""")
```

Error Description :

```
Caused by: org.apache.parquet.io.ParquetDecodingException: Can not read value at 1 in block 0 in file maprfs:///path/disputer/1545555-r-00000.snappy.parquet
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:461)
at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ParquetRecordReader.java:219)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.RecordReaderIterator.hasNext(RecordReaderIterator.scala:39)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:186)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableLong cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableInt
```

Spark Configuration file :

```
spark.driver.memory=10G
spark.executor.memory=23G 
spark.executor.cores=3
spark.executor.instances=100  
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false      
spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files=false  
spark.yarn.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=6144m    
spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1000
spark.shuffle.service=true  
spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1  
spark.broadcastTimeout=36000  
spark.debug.maxToStringFields=100  
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version=2  
spark.network.timeout=600s  
spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader=false
spark.scheduler.listenerbus.eventqueue.capacity=200000  
spark.driver.memoryOverhead=1024  
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=5120  
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC  
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC
```

Answer (score 4):

This issue was occurring due to disabling spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader. spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader=true resolves the issue.

For more details, Visit https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-vectorized-parquet-reader.html